# How stable is Guice 3.0 Beta

Tags: java, guice

**[Guice 3.0 Beta](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Guice30)** is currently (nov. 2010) in Beta. And as a Guice 2.0 user I’m especially interested in the new Hibernate persistence integration (As I believe this is the replacement of the [Guice Warp project](http://code.google.com/p/warp-persist/)). I have some questions and I really like to hear from people who already work with Guice 3.0:

- How stable is the Beta version? Can it be used for production purposes?
- Is the API stabilized? Or is it still under development?
- Is there any target date for the final release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I believe everything's quite stable as far as production-readiness. I believe Google's been using the latest code all along, and I know Maven 3.0 and Nexus are using a slightly modified Guice 3.0.
- I don't think they've frozen things to the point of saying "there will absolutely  be no further API changes before release", but I think anything more than extremely minor changes is unlikely.
- Sam Berlin, one of the guys working on Guice, said that he'd like to have 3.0 out by the end of the year... but the more testing of the snapshot and feedback on it on the mailing list they get, the better.

Answer (score 3):

Why not ask this on their mailing list?  Anyhow from what I can tell they're pretty close, I know that the JClouds guys have been using it heavily and seem pretty happy with it.  I'm using it for the chapter I'm writing on DI for my book and it's passed all of my use cases and tests so far, but I'm not running a production system here :-)

- As a general rule you should be wary of using Beta software in production.  I think when the Guice team say Beta they really do mean Beta (unlike a Web 2.0 Beta site).
- There are possibly still some minor API changes possible, but I think they're pretty much done.  If you're using it purely for JSR-330 DI annotation support then you're probably safe here
- Not that I've seen on their lists, but I could be blind :-)